# How to use external scripts in bundled React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to load `React` and `ReactDOM` externally instead of providing them in the bundle. You can see my attempt at a solution below but it is not working. It works when I put all React calls in the client.js file but it seems to stop working when I try to import components from other files.

How can I use the external `React` in my components and avoid bundling it?

**client.js:**

```
import App from './App.jsx';

let page_initialised = false;

async function init() {
    if (!window.React || !window.ReactDOM) {
        return;
    }
    if (page_initialised) {
        return;
    }
    page_initialised = true;

    ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(document, <App />);
}

init();
document.querySelector('#react').addEventListener('load', init);
document.querySelector('#react_dom').addEventListener('load', init);
```

and have to import App like this too to no avail

```
    const App = await import('./App.jsx');
    ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(document, <App />);
```

**App.jsx:**

```
const Root = React.lazy(() => import('./Root.js'));

export default function App() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  
    return (
      <html>
        <head>
          <script id="react" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js" async></script>
          <script id="react_dom" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js" async></script>
          <script src="/client.js" async></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="root">
            <React.Suspense fallback={<>
              <include src="Root_fallback.html"></include>
            </>}>
              <Root />
            </React.Suspense>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
```

[image]
*Image 1: The error message I'm getting*

[image]
*Image 2: My app structure as seen in the firefox devtools*

Comment: Usually your bundler (in this case it seems to be webpack) has a configuration for external dependencies that shouldn't be included in the bundle, but are dependencies of the output.

I'm not familliar with all the configs of Webpack, so I couldn't tell you exactly what that config is, but I'm sure there's one

Comment: Thank you both! I am new to frontend and webpack, it did have such a configuration setting. This was a much simpler way to solve the issue than what I was attempting to do before.